# Support for using the "iw" command to set the bitrate of a WiFi 6 network card

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi

I setting up my AP on ubuntu 22.04 with hostapd-2.10
I fixed bitrate by "iw", I got:

```
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
```

I think my wifi NIC intel AX201 dose not support

Is there are any WiFi 6 NIC support fixed bitrate?